# cleaner way to assign multi variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any cleaner way to define multiple javascript variables on a single line?

```
var a = 0,
    b = 0,
    c = 0,
    d = 0,
    blah = "";
```

I was wondering if I could write something like this:

```
var a = b = c = d = 0,
    blah = "";
```

Comment: have you tried it in your code?

Comment: Yes, that is allowable, but in my opinion, it's easier to read, and less error prone, to assign a variable per line.

Comment: Why didn't you just test this quite easily using jsFiddle or some such? Both are perfectly valid for strings and integers, but I prefer the first option (allowable for other types)

Comment: No the second way is INCORRECT

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado : do u know what the right way to do so? or where can i read more about it :/

Comment: @Liccy, yes. Read my answer :)

Comment: IMHO, and to expand on Palpatim's comment, the first way you show is as clean as it gets. The second way you propose, or anything similar to that would be more obfuscating than cleaning the code. It's much more natural to have a single variable in a line and, until you basically know yourself the correct syntax of a one-line declaration (indicating it's really being used and not just something rarely used and therefore not really clear), the first way you wrote is perfect.

Comment: Keep It Simple, Stupid — but never oversimplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
var a, b, c, d, blah = "";
a = b = c = d = 0;
```

The second way:

```
var a = b = c = d = 0,  //Wrong!! don't do it
blah = "";
```

It's **wrong** because it would declare only `a` as var and the rest (`b, c, d, e`) would be globals. Terrible side effect (and hard to detect).

However, I'd stick to the long classic one you showed:

```
var a = 0, 
    b = 0, 
    c = 0, 
    d = 0, 
    blah = "";
```

Because it's more standard ;).

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this:

```
var a = b = c = d = 0, blah = "";
```

because the `var` syntax is such that it's only the symbol on the left side of the first `=` that's being declared. You could do this:

```
var a, b, c, d = 0, blah = "";
a = b = c = d;
```

*edit* Further explanation: the first code sample doesn't cause a syntax error (except in "strict" mode), but it doesn't do what it looks like it might do. The variables "b", "c", and "d" are *not* declared as local variables by such a statement. If they're globals, then the pre-existing value would be overridden. Otherwise, they'd be declared implicitly as globals, not as local variables.

In any case, there's nothing really ugly about declaring and initializing variables one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Second way get code with side-effects

Try this:

```
//3 assignments in the 'global' scope
var b = 2,
    c = 3,
    d = 4;

(function(){
    var a = b = 5; //a gets declared in the local scope, 
                   //b get's assigned in the global scope
                   // var a = (b = 5), where (b = 5) returns the value 5 itself
    var d = 5;     //d gets declared in the local scope
}());

console.log(d); //4
console.log(b); //5
console.log(c); //3
console.log(a); //ReferenceError, as a is undefined in this scope
```

Try to use only the first version to avoid receive surprises

Comment: Haha, in the end I could have written a new answer myself I guess, but first I was too lazy and then it got a bit longer :P but whatever :P